# How do you call OnPageIndexChanging from Javascript?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have code that when a user wants to page through a GridView, it asks them (using a JavaScript confirm) if they want to save the data from the grid.
So, I'm able to get the confirm to work (with the code-behind saving function), but I'm noticing that it's not firing the OnPageIndexChanging method - which basically defeats the purpose here.

So, to summarize, can JavaScript access the OnPageIndexChanging method?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

The `OnPageIndexChanging` event is a server-side event, so it's not surprising that your Javascript handler isn't getting triggered.

---

I'm not sure if ASP.Net has a "built in" way to do this; but you can do it by attaching your own Javascript listeners.  Here is the general approach (I'm using JQuery to make it easier):

1. Write a JQuery selector that gets all the paging links that you want to confirm.
2. Add a `click` listener for each of those links
3. Make the *confirm* function the handler for those listeners

So, the code would look something like this:

```
$("#grid a").each(function () {
    $(this).click(function () {
        return confirm("really?");
    });
});
```

<sub>**Notes**</sub>

1. Here `grid` is the ID of the `GridView` control, so `#grid a` selects every `a` tag within my grid.
2. Using `return confirm()` returns *false* if the user does not confirm, which effectively cancels the click event.

Comment: But I can do like this in Javascript:
obj = document.getElementById('<%=ButtonName.ClientID%>');
obj.click();
and the ButtonName's click event gets fired.
I just think that when you do OnPageIndexChanging, you need the GridViewPageEventArgs argument, which I'm not sure how to pass from JavaScript.
Thanks again.

Comment: @kitzur but the `OnPageIndexChanging` is strictly a server-side event.  You need to write a client-side listener to intercept the click, do the confirmation, and then allow the request to continue through to the server.